# How can I unpivot a dataframe with variable date columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, unpivot

I have some input dataframe as the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name":["Ale", "Dan", "Hel"],
        "Project": ["A", "A", "B"],
        "10/04/2023 Formation": [24, 40, 40],
        "17/04/2023 Formation": [12, 24, 24],
        "10/04/2023 Holidays": [40, 40, 40],
        "17/04/2023 Holidays": [12, 40, 24],
     }
)
```

As can be seen, some of the columns are dates belonging to a specific concept (Formation, Holidays, in this case).

What I want is to normalize these columns to convert them into rows (unpivot), but preserving (grouping) each project in its own column; that is, I would like to perform a dataframe transformation whose output would be something like:

```
         Date Name Project  Formation  Holidays
0  10/04/2023  Ale       A         24        40
1  17/04/2023  Ale       A         12        12
2  10/04/2023  Dan       A         40        40
3  17/04/2023  Dan       A         24        40
4  10/04/2023  Hel       B         40        40
5  17/04/2023  Hel       B         24        40
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name":["Ale", "Dan", "Hel"],
        "Project": ["A", "A", "B"],
        "10/04/2023 Formation": [24, 40, 40],
        "17/04/2023 Formation": [12, 24, 24],
        "10/04/2023 Holidays": [40, 40, 40],
        "17/04/2023 Holidays": [12, 40, 24],
     }
)

# Unpivot the data using pd.melt()
df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Name", "Project"], var_name="Date_Concept", value_name="Value")

# Separate the Date and Concept columns
df_melted[["Date", "Concept"]] = df_melted["Date_Concept"].str.split(" ", expand=True)
df_melted = df_melted.drop("Date_Concept", axis=1)

# Use pd.pivot_table() to reshape the dataframe
df_final = pd.pivot_table(df_melted, index=["Date", "Name", "Project"], columns="Concept", values="Value").reset_index()

# Reorder the columns
df_final = df_final[["Date", "Name", "Project", "Formation", "Holidays"]].sort_values(["Name", "Date", "Project"])

print(df_final)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pd.wide_to_long` after renaming columns to switch prefix and suffix information (10/04/2023 Formation -> Formation-10/04/2023):

```
out = pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns=lambda x: '-'.join(x.split(maxsplit=1)[::-1])),
                      stubnames=['Formation', 'Holidays'], i=['Name', 'Project'],
                      j='Date', sep='-', suffix='.*').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Name Project        Date  Formation  Holidays
0  Ale       A  10/04/2023         24        40
1  Ale       A  17/04/2023         12        12
2  Dan       A  10/04/2023         40        40
3  Dan       A  17/04/2023         24        40
4  Hel       B  10/04/2023         40        40
5  Hel       B  17/04/2023         24        24
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor)'s [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

out = df.pivot_longer(['Name', 'Project'], sort_by_appearance=True,
                      names_to=('Date', '.value'),
                      names_pattern=r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) (.*)')
```

Or `names_sep=' '` in place of `names_pattern=r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) (.*)'`.

Output:

```
  Name Project        Date  Formation  Holidays
0  Ale       A  10/04/2023         24        40
1  Ale       A  17/04/2023         12        12
2  Dan       A  10/04/2023         40        40
3  Dan       A  17/04/2023         24        40
4  Hel       B  10/04/2023         40        40
5  Hel       B  17/04/2023         24        24
```